# Show that : $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k{n\choose k}\over (k+1)^2}={1+\sqrt{1+4(n+1)^2H_nH_{n+1}}\over 2(n+1)^2}$, for $n\ge0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, binomial-coefficients, harmonic-numbers

Show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k{n\choose k}\over (k+1)^2}={1+\sqrt{1+4(n+1)^2H_nH_{n+1}}\over 2(n+1)^2}$$

$H_n$; is the n-th harmonic number

My try:

We know that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\over (k+1)^2}=\int_{0}^{1}{-\ln{x}\over 1+x}dx$$

But

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k{n\choose k}\over (k+1)^2}=\int_{0}^{a}???$$

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) I found

$$H_n=\int_{0}^{1}{1-x^n\over 1-x}dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}{{n\choose k}\over k}$$ may be of useful

Onward I am clueless as what to do next. Please help!

Comment: The result is irrational ?

Comment: Numerically I have check for a few values of n and it is fine, unless you or anyone can show that it is irrational, then the sum on the LHS is then be wrong.

Comment: It seems that $1+4(n+1)^2H_nH_{n+1}$ always be a square number! But I can't prove it.

Comment: If you exploit $H_{n+1}=H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}$ that is trivial.

Comment: Yah , it looked quite scary when I saw it, It didn't make since the left is a sequence of finite  rationals and the right has a square root.

Comment: Thank you to you and @jack D. For nicely answer the question

Comment: @X-men, ur welcome. Sounds like you are interested in series and integrals. Pretty fun to play with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by the binomial expansion

$$\sum^n_{k=0} {n \choose k} x^k = (1+x)^n$$

By integration

$$\sum^n_{k=0} {n \choose k} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} =\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$$

Integrating again

$$\sum^n_{k=0} {n \choose k} \frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{(k+1)^2} =\frac{1}{n+1}\int^{-1}_0\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{x}\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1}\int^{1}_0\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}-1}{x}\,dx$$

By substitution

$$\sum^n_{k=0} {n \choose k} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(k+1)^2} =\frac{1}{n+1}\int^{1}_0\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\,dx = \frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1} $$

Note that

\begin{align}
\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4(n+1)^2H_nH_{n+1}}}{n+1} &= \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4(n+1)^2H_n^2+4(n+1)H_n}}{n+1}\\&=\frac{ 1+\sqrt{(1+2(n+1)H_n)^2}}{n+1}
\\&=\frac{2+2(n+1)H_n}{2(n+1)^2} \\&= \frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Since $\frac{1}{(1+k)^2}=\int_{0}^{1} x^k(-\log x)\,dx $ we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2} &=& \int_{0}^{1}(-\log x)\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-x)^k\,dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}(-\log x)(1-x)^n\,dx\\&=&-\int_{0}^{1}x^n\log(1-x)\,dx\\&=&-\left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^{\alpha}\,dx\,\right|_{\alpha=0^+}\\&=&-\left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\,\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}\,\right|_{\alpha=0^+}\\&=&\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1} \end{eqnarray*}$$
and since $H_{n+1}=H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}$,
$$ 1+4(n+1)^2 H_n H_{n+1} = 1+4(n+1) H_n + 4(n+1)^2 H_n^2 = (1+2(n+1)H_n)^2.$$